# setTimeout not working,am I missing something here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I know its pretty basic but I just can't get it to work.  it keeps throwing "Object Expected" error...

```
 $(document).ready(function(){   
    setTimeout('showMessage()', 1000); 

    function showMessage() { 
        alert('abc');
    } 
    });
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have wrapped your function in quotes, so it treats it like a string, not as the object it's expecting, so, like SLaks said:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){   
    setTimeout(showMessage, 1000); 

    function showMessage() { 
        alert('abc');
    } 
    });
```

Comment: If providing a downvote, please provide a reason why. I don't see a reason here.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the reason someone did is most likely that string arguments to `setTimeout()` are perfectly fine: the problem lies with visibility of variables

Answer (score 8):

You've got a scoping problem: `showMessage()` is only visible withing the anonymous function, but when the parameter to `setTimeout()` gets evaluated, the runtime already left the scope.

Use the function directly as argument to `setTimeout()` and get rid of the evil[TM] string evaluation:

```
setTimeout(showMessage, 1000);
```

Answer (score 6):

The `setTimeout` method is best used with a function, not a string.  Therefore, the best way to do this would be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(showMessage, 1000);
});

function showMessage() { 
    alert('abc');
}
```

Comment: +1 for "best used", correctly implying it can be used with a string (but, of course, shouldn't be).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the showMessage function is declared within the ready event and setTimeout("showMessage()", 1000) will look for it in the global scope. You can move its declaration to a global scope, e.g. out of ready event, or use the SLaks answer: setTimeout(showMessage, 1000)